# Setting TextBox so user cannot type in non-Numeric characters or spaces

Tags: vb.net, textbox

Is there a way to set a `TextBox` in `vb` such that it does not accept a space or a non-Numeric character entered by a user? I am writing a program that has a `TextBox` called `phoneField` in which the user should type in only numbers and if the user trys to type a non-Numeric character or space, nothing should be displayed in the `TextBox`. How could that be done?

Comment: there is mask property in MaskedTextBox

Answer (score 2):

First use 0's in your mask to allow only numeric characters.
Second, assign the ResetOnSpace property to false

> Me.MaskedTextBox.ResetOnSpace = False

This will reject any spaces the user enters unless it is part of the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong way to handle this. You'll drive your users insane with rage at your app. Instead, let them enter whatever they want, and have code on the backend that first strips out any non-digit and then validates the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MaskedTextBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx)

something alike:

```
Me.MaskedTextBox1.Mask = "0-000-0000000"
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Alessa. I have added the maskedtextbox control and set mask in this way `Me.MaskedTextBox1.Mask = "0000 000 000"
` but there is one problem still; it accepts spaces. I want it to only accept numbers

Comment: strange because 0 must not allow spaces http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx but 9 does. Provide more information about what do you use.

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar to this using an inherited TextBox control.

The bonus of this way of doing it is it allows cut, copy and paste to function correctly.

```
''' <summary>
''' A TextBox control that only allows numeric input
''' </summary>
''' <remarks>Allows cut, copy and paste</remarks>
Public Class NumericTextBox
    Inherits TextBox
    Private _textBefore As String = ""
    Protected Overrides Sub OnTextChanged(e As System.EventArgs)
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        If MyBase.Text.Length > 0 AndAlso Not IsNumeric(MyBase.Text) Then
            ' The text has been changed to a non numeric value
            Dim selectionStart As Integer = MyBase.SelectionStart
            MyBase.Text = _textBefore
            MyBase.SelectionStart = selectionStart
        Else
            ' The current text is numeric (or blank) remember it in case it changes to an invalid value
            _textBefore = MyBase.Text
        End If
        MyBase.OnTextChanged(e)
        Me.ResumeLayout()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the correct settings that work if your prompt character is a space:

```
    .AllowPromptAsInput = False    
    .Mask = "00"     
    .ResetOnPrompt = False
    .ResetOnSpace = True
```